# Effective sample size when the estimated proportion is zero

Tags: survey-sampling, design-based-inference

In order to estimate the proportion of fradulent invoices, we did a two-stage probability weighted sample. A *subset* $m$ out of $M$ departments were chosen in the first stage, and $n_m$ invoices were then chosen in each department, so the total sample size is $n=\sum n_m$. First- and second order inclusion probabilities were computed based on this sampling design.

To obtain confidence intervals, we computed the design effect and effective sample size as described e.g. in [Korn & Graubard (1998)](https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/en/pub/12-001-x/1998002/article/4356-eng.pdf?st=ilF20QBv).

We discovered no fraudulent invoice, so our estimated proportion is $\hat{p}=0$. In such a case, [Korn & Graubard (1998, p. 195)](https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/en/pub/12-001-x/1998002/article/4356-eng.pdf?st=ilF20QBv) suggest to set the effective sample size equal to the actual sample size.

But this feels not right: our sampling design is certainly less precise than simple random sampling, because we selected only a subset of all departments in the first stage. So, had we discovered only a single fraudulent invoice, our effective sample size would have been perhaps half the actual sample size, and confidence intervals much wider accordingly.

Is there a better way to estimate the effective sample size when the estimated proportion is precisely zero?